# Conditional Expectation of Binomial Given $X \leq x$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Are there any neat formulas to reduce something like $\sum_{i=0}^{x} i \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$ where $x<n$?

This would be proportional to $\mathbb{E}(X\leq x)$ where $X$~$\text{Bin}(n,p)$. We'd just have to divide by $\Pr(X\leq x)$. I realize there are a lot of asymptotic results, but I'd like to be able to consider small $n$.

Comment: No. You're going to have to just add up the cases if you want it to hold for small n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you'd call it "neat", but it can be expressed using a hypergeometric function:

$$np - \left( x+1 \right) {n\choose x+1}{p}^{x+1} \left( 1-p \right) ^{n-
x-1}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left([1,1-n+x],\;[x+1],\,{\frac {-p}{1-p}}\right)}
$$